# Como puedo hacer un request por medio de Ajax?

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

***Tengo este objeto en mi archivo js***

```js
var objMascota;
function CrearObjeto()
{
    objMascota =
    {
        Dueño: $("#txtDueño").val(),
        Nombre: $("#txtNombre").val(),
        Raza: $("#txtRaza").val(),
        Nacimiento: $("#idFechaNac").val(),
        Sexo: $("#idSexo").val(),
        Edad: $("#txtEdad").val(),
        Color: $("#txtColor").val(),
        Comentarios: $("#txtcomentarios").val(),
        fnSaludo: function () {
            alert(" Hola humano, mi nombre es " + this.Nombre + " tengo " + this.Edad + " años " + " y mi dueño(a) " + this.Dueño + " me ama mucho ");
            console.log(" Dueño: " + this.Dueño + "\n", "Nombre: " + this.Nombre + "\n", "Raza: " + this.Raza + "\n", "Fecha de nacimiento: " + this.Nacimiento + "\n", "Sexo: " + this.Sexo + "\n", "Edad: " + this.Edad + "\n", "Color: " + this.Color + "\n", "Cualidades: " + this.Comentarios + "\n");
            return false;
        }
    };
    return false;
}
$("#btnCrearObjeto").click(function ()
{
    CrearObjeto();
});

$("#btnSaludo").click(function ()
{
    objMascota.fnSaludo();
    return false;
});
```

**Al crear ese objeto se debe de hacer un request por medio de Ajax donde se envié el objeto resultante a un archivo generic handler (.ashx) por medio de URL, retornar un mensaje de notificación y mostrarlo al usuario.**

Answer (score 0):

Esto es una petición simple AJAX, como estas manejando un objeto debes convertirlo a String con JSON.stringify. De esta manera en tu pagina de destino, debes usar una función para decodificarlo y poder leer su estructura.

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/myDir/MyFile.ashx',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType: "json",
    data : {
        'obj' : JSON.stringify(objMascota)
    },
    success : function(data) {              
        alert('Response: '+data.response);
    },
    error : function(request,error){
        alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
    }
});
```

Intenta en tu archivo .ashx imprimir solo un texto para saber que tu llamado AJAX esta funcionando.

```
outputToReturn = String.Format("{ \"response\" : \"OK\"  }", "SUCCESS" );
context.Response.Write(outputToReturn);
```

Observa que el AJAX se incluye el parametro dataType: "json", quiere decir que el sistema espera un String para convertirlo en JSON, luego se lo asigna a la variable "data" de la función "success".

Obviamente ese AJAX que te dejo debes llamarlo luego de crear el objeto, sino no enviará nada.